# how to get text between 2 string and ended with punctuation list

Tags: python

I'm newbie in python
I want to take a sentence between 2 strings with end

```
/. or /? or /, or /!
```

The code I have tried

```
START = "What"
END = "\.|\?"
test = """What is your name? My name is aaaaa.  """

m = re.compile('(%s)(.*?)%s' % (START,END), flags = re.IGNORECASE)
a = m.search(test).group(2)
```

I want to take the sentence "is your name?" but the priority in end list first must "."  and second "\?"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. I don't see `/.`, `/?`, `/,`, or `/!` anywhere. What is your expected output? What output are you getting? And what on earth does the second to last sentence in your question mean?

Comment: my expected output is
"is your name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get individual sentences. In that case, you can use [`TextBlob`](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/)

```
from textblob import TextBlob
tb = TextBlob("""What is your name? My name is aaaaa.  """)
print tb.sentences
```

This returns a list of `Sentence` objects:

```
[Sentence("What is your name?"), Sentence("My name is aaaaa.  ")]
```

Comment: how to take only the sentence "My name is aaaa."?

Comment: If you always have a question/answer sentence pair, you can do `tb.sentences[1]` and get the "My name is..." sentence.